# How to programmatically add XML namespace declarations to document in WPF?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, rss

I have an existing XML document parsed as an XDocument in WPF. Need to add namespace declarations programmatically in C# so I can change

`<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">`

To

`<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">`

I'll add the tags later but the issue is how to edit the declarations. I've seen some similar questions but none answer this specific one.

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively easy by using LINQ to XML API.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    // Create an XML tree in a namespace, with a specified prefix
    XNamespace ns = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/";
    
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<rss xmlns:itunes='http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd'/>");
    xdoc.Root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "content", ns.NamespaceName));
    
    Console.Write(xdoc);
}
```

**Output**

```
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" />
```